# Можно ли использовать реальную клавиатуру компьютера в android эмуляторе?

Tags: android

Конечно бред, но программа будет запускаться в эмуляторе на компьютере, и нужно чтобы программа реагировала на нажатия кнопок с клавиатуры. Через какие библиотеки это можно воплотить?

Comment: Какой эмулятор будете использовать?

Comment: Если у вас `Genymotion` эмулятор, то перед запуском конкретного устройства можно в его настройках отключить использование виртуальной клавы.

Comment: Ок виртуальную клавиатуру смогу отключить, а с реальной смогу работать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

Как заявлено https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studios-emulator-for-android/ :

you can use your computer’s keyboard to enter text in the emulator

> Вы можете использовать клавиатуру компьютера для ввода текста в
>   эмуляторе.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы при нажатии к примеру на "W"  выполнялся определённый код..А не набирать текст..

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной попробуйте `@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getKeyCode() == neededKeyCode) {
            //TODO необходимый код
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }`